# SortedLinkedList Remove methods head, tail, between two nodes

Tags: java, sortedlist

I need to remove a key in SortedLinkedList, but I can't. There is no syntax error but code doesn't work. Deleting methods for begging, ending and middle of the node list. Here is my remove methods:

```
    public void Remove(int key){

      LinkedListNode find = Find(key);
      if(find == null){
          System.out.println("Item is not found.");
      return;}

      LinkedListNode helper = new LinkedListNode();
        helper.next = head;
        LinkedListNode p = helper;

        while(p.next != null){
            if(p.next.key == key){
                LinkedListNode next = p.next;
                p.next = next.next; 
            }else{
                p = p.next;
            }
            return;
        } 
        noOfNodes--; 
    }

    public void Remove(LinkedListNode node)  {
        Remove(node.key);
    }
```

another code:

```
     public void Remove(int key){
      LinkedListNode temp = Find(key);
      if(temp==null)
      {
          System.out.println("Item not found");
          return;
      }
      if(head==tail){
          head=null;
          tail=null;
      }

     else if(temp.key==head.key){
             head=temp.next;
                 head.prev=null;
         //
     }else if(temp.key==tail.key){
         tail=tail.prev;
         tail.next=null;
     }else { 
         temp.prev.next=temp.next;
         temp.next.prev=temp.prev;
     }
         noOfNodes--;
  } 

     public void Remove(LinkedListNode node){
     Remove(node.key);
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you set head? right now I think it would not compile...

Comment: Please bemore specific. What exactly does not work? Do you get an error? Which kind of?

Comment: there is no error but run time error. i remove something head and print my list and removing node still there. same situation tail node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here :

```
while(p.next != null){
            if(p.next.key == key){
                LinkedListNode next = p.next;
                p.next = next.next; 
            }else{
                p = p.next;
            }
            return;  //--> why are you returning here ... Line 1
        }
```

Returning from Line 1, means you have just checked the first value, weather its equal to key or not equal to key, you are just breaking the while loop and returning to calling method or parent method. Which definitely doesn't remove the value.

Comment: i deleted return and run again. i removed middle and tail but not head. head its not working.

Comment: let me check code again... also if you liked my answer please accept it.

Comment: and i just realised. code is deleting list but list view doesnt delete.

example :
+--------+--------+
| INDEX  |   KEY  |
+--------+--------+
|0| 1|
|1| 2|
+--------+--------+
| The list has 1 nodes
+--------+--------+
----------------------------------------------------------

Comment: if(head==tail){    // --> this condition must include one more condition i.e. head.key == tail.key i.e. case where only one element and the element is key.
          head=null;
          tail=null;
      }

Comment: i got it. its woking now :) thanks a lot but complete code included test its not display what i want :( everything is fine but grade is not what i want grade.

Comment: welcome, but please upload full code, or explain more about the problem.